# Use Memo combine into single condition

Tags: reactjs

I have added the conditon to check the header and footer is value or not

````
        const hasHeader = !!(children as React.ReactNode[]).find((e) =>
          isComponentType(el, Header)
        );
        return {
          header,
        };
      }, [children]);```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const hasChildComponent = (Component) => {
  return !!(children as React.ReactNode[]).find((el) => isComponentType(el, Component));
}

return {
  hasHeader: hasChildComponent(Modal.Header),
  hasFooter: hasChildComponent(Modal.Footer),
}
```

Comment: ```const ctxValue = useMemo(() => {
        const hasChildComponent = (Component) => {
          !!(children as React.ReactNode[]).find((el) =>
            isComponentType(el, Component)
          );
        };

        return {
          hasHeader: hasChildComponent(Modal.Header),
          hasFooter: hasChildComponent(Modal.Footer),
        };
      }, [children]);```

      console.log(ctxValue);
I tried this but i am getting undefined instead of true value

Comment: You're missing the return statement in `hasChildComponent`.